# How to retrieve implementing class/interface of parent interface?

Tags: java, spring, oop

I am clear with polymorphism and inheritance concept of oop, but I am in a situation where I need to know the implementing class. For example:

```
public CommonReadRepository<?> getReadRepository(String tableName) {
        if (tableName == null)
            return null;
        switch (tableName) {
        case "order":
            return orderRepository;
        ...
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The interface `orderRepository` extends `CommonReadRepository`, and because of my requirement, I need to access a function defined in  orderRepository.

```
CommonReadRepository<?> repository=getReadRepository("order");
```

Is there any way to check back the implementing (child) class or interface of `CommonReadRepository`?

Of course, I can always do something like this:

```
if(tableName=="order")
return (OrderRepository)CommonReadRepository<?>;
```

I tried to debug `getReadRepository("order")`, but it gives me an instance of `JdkDynamicAopProxy`, and I am not sure how it works.

> if(interface is instanceof xyz class) 
>   i do not want to use it because i have 100 of classes and i want to keep it as a last resort... or in other words
>    i don't know about xyz class

Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking... Can't you use ```instanceof``` or ```getClass()``` ?

Comment: If you need to access that method, you should use a parameter type that includes it. This sounds like a design problem.

Answer (score 1):

Following is one way to check if the returned Object is an instance of the specified class:

`CommonReadRepository<?> repository=getReadRepository("order");
if(repository instanceof WhatEverSubclass) {
// do something
}`

But using this approach is not how OOP is supposed to be done. If your classes all implement the same Interface, why don't you define a common method, that's then used in all the subclasses, but implement it differently every time.

Comment: The interface could have a self-identifier that the implementing classes must provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you try to do is not getting you anywhere.

You can find all available classes inheriting an interface using the reflections tool (https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections). I used it for a dependency injector and it works very reliable.

Yet, why don't you just use the instanceof operator to make sure the object is of the right type:

```
if( repository instanceof OrderRepository) return (OrderRepository)repository;
```

But still, this won't change the return type of your function and you need to inspect the type of the returned value again outside of your function.

Update: If this happens for hundreds of objects, you could change the getRepository method to return a type you give as parameter: `<T> getRepository(String name, Class<T> expectedType)`

This will allow you `OrderRepository o = getRepository("order", OrderRepository.class);`

Comment: i cant use instanceof ,i have 100+ classes and checking it with instanceof  is last resort